# How to create a check in a table so user can't go to the same places twice unless 6 months have pass

Tags: postgresql

I need a way to make a CHECK (if the user have been to the same place in the last 6 months the input will not be allow to happen)
Here is my schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA code

CREATE TABLE code.place ( 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE code.user ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8),
   data DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_user_id) REFERENCES code.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_place_id) REFERENCES code.place
);
```

I have the code to show a table where only users that haven´t been to a place in the last 6 months will appear in the table. But I need to put this as a check in my visit table, so no employee will put this information on the visit table, but i am finding myself not capable of doing it so.

```
SELECT pk_place_id, pk_user_id, date
    FROM visita_polo
    WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM age(NOW(),data))*12 + EXTRACT(month FROM age(now(),data)) > 6;
```

Comment: 1) Where is `visita_polo` defined. 2) Look at using `range` constraints per here [Constraints on Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the `btree_gist` extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Then create your table with the following exclusion.

```
CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3)
, pk_place_id VARCHAR(8)
,        data DATE
,  CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_user_id) REFERENCES code.user
,  CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_place_id) REFERENCES code.place
,     EXCLUDE USING gist (pk_user_id WITH =, pk_place_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '6 months')::date) WITH &&)
);
```

Now let's put some data in.

```
INSERT INTO code.user
     VALUES ('ABC', 'Albert Brian Cohen')
;

INSERT INTO code.place
     VALUES ('MADRID', 'Madrid, Spain')
;

INSERT INTO code.visit
     VALUES ('ABC', 'MADRID', CURRENT_DATE)
;
```

So far, so good.

```
INSERT INTO code.visit
     VALUES ('ABC', 'MADRID', CURRENT_DATE + interval '5 months')
;
```

Returns an exclusion constraint violation error. Oops! Not enough time passed.

```
INSERT INTO code.visit
     VALUES ('ABC', 'MADRID', CURRENT_DATE + interval '6 months')
;
```

Inserts as expected. All good!

The database will do this for you. No need to try and enforce this at the application layer especially since the app layer is subject to race conditions. Better to handle this at the data layer so that even application bugs cannot silently corrupt your data.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! I will be testing it tomorrow at work.

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and I had the following problem: The code doesn't allow the user to go somewhere if they have been somewhere in the last 6 months, but what I need is that blocks user from going to a place they HAVE BEEN already in the last 6 months

Comment: I tried using :
EXCLUDE USING gist (pk_place_id AND pk_user_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '6 months')::date) WITH &&)
But its says that it is a sintaxe error.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I have fixed the exclusion constraint. You were on the right track. You just need to remember the "WITH =" part which defines how the comparison is made for the pk_place_id column.